# Cakephp 2.5.3 Form Validation Exception

Tags: php, forms, validation

I am trying to create an exception when validating an email field.  The only user who is not required to enter an email is those where role == 5. They are recipients of charitable help and many do not have emails. But we want to collect the email if they have one.

In my validation I have tried many things to the tune of a custom validation rule:

```
public $validate = array (
        'email' => array(
            'emailException' => array(
            'rule'    => array('emailException'),
            'message' => 'Please provide a valid email address.',
            )
           )
         );

function emailException() {

        $role = $this->data['Person']['role'];
        $email = $this->data['Person']['email'];

        if($role != 5 && empty($email) ){
           return false; 
        }else{
           return true; 
        }

 }
```

This has no effect (saves as if there was no rule)

unset looked promising thought I could wrap it in an if statement:

```
    $validator = $this->validator();
    unset($validator['email']['required']);
```

But I am unsure where to implement this or if it would even work.

Thanks for your help!